# Django form submit button not working in google map javascript

Tags: javascript, django, google-maps

I am trying to move the submit button for a form on a google map. I can move the button, but it is not submitting after I reposition it with javascript. Here is my code:

template

```
<form method="POST" class="post-form" id="thing">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button id="saving" type="submit" class="save btn btn-default controls">Let's Go!</button>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Where do you want to go?">
    {% csrf_token %}
</form>


<div id="map"></div>
```

javascript in template

```
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    var homeControlDiv = document.getElementById('saving');
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(homeControlDiv);
```

views.py

```
def search(request):
    form = LocationInput()
    if request.method == "POST":
        print '1'
        form = LocationInput(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print '2'
            t = Trip(trip_name = form.cleaned_data['city'])
            t.save()
            if Location.objects.filter(google_id=form.cleaned_data['google_id']).exists():
                l = Location.objects.get(google_id=form.cleaned_data['google_id'])
                l.trips.add(t)
                l.save()
            else:
                form.save()
                l = Location.objects.get(google_id=form.cleaned_data['google_id'])
                l.trips.add(t)
                l.save()
            if request.user.is_authenticated():
                t.owner = request.user
                t.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/trips/')
            else:
                request.session['trip-id'] = t.id
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/auth/') 
    return render(request, 'frontpage/search.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class LocationInput(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        widgets = {
            'name' : forms.TextInput(attrs = {'placeholder': 'I want to go to...', 'size': '15', 'type': 'hidden'}),
            'google_id' : forms.TextInput(attrs = {'type': 'hidden'}),  
            'address' : forms.TextInput(attrs = {'type': 'hidden'}),
            'city' : forms.TextInput(attrs = {'type': 'hidden'}),
            'lat' : forms.TextInput(attrs = {'type': 'hidden'}),
            'lng' : forms.TextInput(attrs = {'type': 'hidden'}),   
            'trips' : forms.TextInput(attrs = {'type': 'hidden'}),  

        }
        fields = ('name', 'google_id', 'address', 'city', 'lat', 'lng', 'trips')
```

If I take away id="saving" then it works perfectly.

Comment: It looks like you are moving the button outside of its parent `form`. If you do this, it will not do anything because it is no longer part of the `form`.

Comment: It is being moved with javascript, will that also take it outside the parent form?

Comment: Yes, it will I think.